# Infinitely many times differentiable function with unbounded derivatives?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be an infinitely many times continuously differentiable function on the compact interval $[0,1]$.

We denote by $f^{(k)}$ the $k$-th derivative with respect to $x$.

Then we know: $\sup_{x \in [0,1] } | f^{(k)} (x) | = a_k < \infty$ for all $k$.

**Question:**

Is then also $ \sup_{k} \sup_{x \in [0,1] } | f^{(k)} (x) | < \infty$?

i.e. does $a_k$ converge?

Comment: What are the derivatives of $x\mapsto e^{2x}$?

Comment: Besides, much more fascinating: Taylor Series of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for $-1<x<1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for your question is no.

The function $f(x)=e^{2x}$ is $C^\infty$, and $f^{(k)}(x) = 2^ke^{2x}$.
This means using your notation that $a_k \geq 2^k$ for all $k$.
Thus $a_k \to \infty$ as $k\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It the sequence $(a_k)_{k\geqslant 0}$ is bounded, then the function $f$ is [real analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) on the interval $(0,1)$, which is stronger than being smooth.

In general, the sequence $(a_k)_{k\geqslant 0}$ can grow to infinity arbitrarily fast. This can be seen using a theorem by Borel, which states that given a sequence $(c_k)_{k\geqslant 0}$ we can find a smooth function $f$ such that $f^{(k)}(1/2)=a_k$ for each integer $k\geqslant 0$.